# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth has different effect on UILabel than on UITextField

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uilabel

I have an `UILabel` (named `label`) and an `UITextField` (named `textField`) set up such that they do have the same frame size and both do have `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` enabled. In addition to that I set `minimumFontSize` for `textField` and a large initial font size for `label` and `textField`. This should - according to what I read - lead to "auto-shrink" the font size of the contained text. So far so good.

As a matter of fact this leads to shrinking of the text for both `label` and `textField`, but to my surprise with different results. While the `label` font seams to be shrunk to fit the label bounding rectangle, the `textField` font is shrunk to fit the `textField`'s width, but not its height. Here is a picture of the output (`label` on top, `textField` on bottom):

[image: textField label difference]

The documentation of `UITextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` explicitly states:

> Normally, the text field’s content is drawn with the font you specify in the font property. If this property is set to true, however, and the contents in the text property exceed the **text field’s bounding rectangle**, the receiver starts reducing the font size until the string fits or the minimum font size is reached. The text is shrunk along the baseline.

**This leaves me confused about the shrinking behavior of `textField`. Any ideas why this is happening? How do I achieve the same result for `textField` as I do for `label`?**

Here is the complete playground code to generate the above image (I used autolayout, but the same thing happens when I use fixed frames):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// setup liveView
var viewSize = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 600.0)
let liveView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: viewSize))
liveView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
let topView = UIView()
topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
liveView.addSubview(topView)
topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.topAnchor).isActive = true
topView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
topView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
let bottomView = UIView()
bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
liveView.addSubview(bottomView)
bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
bottomView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
bottomView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: liveView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = liveView

// setup label
let labelSize = 0.5 * CGSize(width: liveView.frame.width, height: liveView.frame.height)
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.5 * labelSize.width, y: 0.5 * labelSize.height), size: labelSize))
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.text = "0"
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 1000.0)
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
topView.addSubview(label)
label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

// setup textField
let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.5 * labelSize.width, y: 0.5 * labelSize.height), size: labelSize))
textField.text = "0"
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
textField.minimumFontSize = 10.0
textField.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 1000.0)
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bottomView.addSubview(textField)
textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fair to say that `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` only ***"mostly"*** works.

It is also primarily for use with string *width*.

Also, `UILabel` and `UITextField` do not use the same font rendering, and do not have the same bounding-box (text fields have an inset).

If you want both elements to have the same ***visual*** behaviors, your best bet is to use a `UITextField` with user interaction disabled instead of a `UILabel`.

Comment: Fair enough and honestly what I expected. So do you think the documentation on `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` for `UITextField` is just wrong? Because inset or not, the text does not seem to be fitted inside the bounding rectangle.

Comment: @Wizard - I'm not an Apple engineer, so I can only guess. Either the docs are wrong, or just not clear. Again, I think the **primary use** is for string width... particularly with `UITextField` where it is much more common to use the intrinsic height of the text field - based on the font - rather than adjusting the font based on a constrained text field height.